# C++ Eigen - How to combine broadcasting and elementwise operations

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a MatrixXf variable and a VectorXf variable. I would like to perform a rowwise division using the Vector on my Matrix. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    MatrixXf mat(3, 2);
    mat << 1, 2,
           3, 4,
           5, 6;
    VectorXf vec(2);
    vec << 2, 3;
    mat = mat.rowwise() / vec;
    cout << mat << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting to get a matrix with value [0.5, 0.667; 1.5, 1.333; 2.5, 2].

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the matrix and vector as arrays (and not linear algebra objects, see [docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html)). To do so, you would rewrite the relevant line as:

```
mat = mat.array().rowwise() / vec.transpose().array();
cout << mat << endl; // Note that in the original this was vec
```

The `transpose` is needed as the `VectorXf` is a column vector by definition, and you wanted a row vector.

Comment: This solved my problem above. While I have another problem for broadcasting. It is possible to perform the broadcasting operation for + and - without the .array() syntax according to the document. Why I need to use the array() method for doing multiplication and division?

Comment: @yc2986 To quote the documentation, "The Array class provides general-purpose arrays, as opposed to the Matrix class which is intended for linear algebra." Addition and subtraction are operations that are defined for linear algebra as well (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations)), whereas coefficient wise multiplication and division by another matrix or vector are not.